# Can subsonic handle spatial data. If so how?

Tags: subsonic, geometry, spatial, geography

I've been using subsonic for quite a while now and I seem pretty confident about using it in my thesis. What I'm not sure about is how will it handle geometry data types. Anyone has an idea??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently SubSonic cannot handle geometry types. It's on the roadmap for future release.